# How to get value of element from string using DOM?

Tags: java, xml, string, dom

I have next code written on Java:

```
public class XMLParser {

public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
    String message = "<add>\n" +
            "  <doc>\n" +
            "    ......................
            "    <field name=\"imageWidth\" update=\"set\">400</field><field name=\"imageHeight\" update=\"set\">400</field>\n" +
            "    <field name=\"internalImageUrl\" update=\"set\">https://google.com</field>\n" +
            "  </doc>\n" +
            "</add>";

    String s = getUrlValue(message);

    System.out.println(s);
}

private static String getUrlValue(String message) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {
    String urlValue = null;
    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(message));

    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("doc");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

        NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("field");
        Element line = (Element) name.item(23);
        urlValue = line.getTextContent();
    }

    return urlValue;
}
```

}

How I can get the value of this attribute:

```
field name=\"internalImageUrl\" update=\"set\">https://google.com</field>
```

I need to get link -> `"https://google.com"` 
using `"internalImageUrl"` parameter

In my solution I used:

```
Element line = (Element) name.item(23);
```

but I need use loop fon all elements named `"field"` and find just `"internalImageUrl"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[xPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)** can make it more easy,the expression is `//field[name='internalImageUrl']`

In [Dom4j](https://dom4j.github.io/) we can use below code to get all the nodes that meet your demands

```
  List list = doc.selectNodes("//field[name='internalImageUrl']");  
  Iterator it = list.iterator();  
  while (it.hasNext()) {  

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I just used "//field[@name='internalImageUrl']"